# EasyEDA: The clearance between two objects is less than the Design Rule Checking (DRC) clearance which has different nets

Tags: pcb, pcb-design

I am currently working on a DIY project for which I decided to design a custom PCB using EasyEDA. However, after auto routing the copper traces for most of the PCB, I had to manually connect the last few wires/traces. When doing so I got two errors from the DRC and I don't know how to solve them. I would guess it did not connect the traces properly, but I am not able to solve them on my own and could not find an answer to my question anywhere else.
Thanks in advance!

[image: Error 1] 
[image]

Comment: Changing the clearance settings seems the most likely action to take.

Comment: @Andyaka Thank you, but I am a complete beginner: How can I do it?

Comment: Yeah I know you are a beginner because you used an autorouter and nobody experienced ever does this. Sorry can't help - I don't use EDA. Keep going through the menus until you find the user-alterable numbers. Every cad package has them somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyword you are looking for is **rules**. In EasyEDA you access rules via: *Tools > Design Rule*.
EasyEDA has [documentation](https://docs.easyeda.com/en/PCB/Design-Rule-Check/index.html) on their web site. Rules are not only important for autorouting, but for the *design rule check* (DRC) that use these numbers to check your board.

Learn how to manually route first. Using an autorouter is an advanced topic which requires careful application of rules. Blindly using an autorouter will get you in trouble; simplistic autorouters, like EasyEDA's autorouter, often perform poorly; and any autorouter stifles your learning process in optimal parts placement visualization.